# Traces of operators in nuclear spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, nuclear-spaces

I am currently reading up on nuclear spaces in Jarchow, "Locally Convex Spaces", but I got confused and don't seem to find my mistake. In said book, theorem 21.5.9 states:

Let $F$ be a nuclear Frechet space. Then, $F'_\beta \otimes_{\pi} F = L_\beta (F,F)$.
i.e. the projective tensor product of $F$ with its strong dual is homeomorphic to the operators on $F$ with the strong topology.

Now, that means every operator on $F$ has a trace, right?

So take the the space $X=\Pi_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{R}$. This is a nuclear Frechet space as it is a countable infinite product of those. Let $id_k : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the identity on the k'th component of $X$. We have $id_X = \Sigma_k id_k$. Now, by above theorem $id_X$ and all $id_k$ must be trace class, but clearly, the sum can not converge to $id_X$ as otherwise the trace must be infinite.

If I read correctly, the strong topology has a 0-basis of $L(B,U)$, maps from some bounded set into an open set. The partial sums $f_n=\Sigma_{1≤k≤n}
id_k$ however satisfy that $f_n-id_X$ is zero on the first $n$ components and thus maps any set into a chosen open set for n big enough. Thus, the partial sum converges and there is a contradiction.

I simply can't spot my mistake, perhaps you can help me?

Comment: In the stereotype world, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_space, this equality is not true: ${\mathbb R}_{\mathbb N}\circledast {\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N}\ne {\mathcal L}({\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N})$.

Comment: That might be, but for Nuclear Frechet Spaces and the projective tensor product, it holds.

Comment: Something is strange for me here... For a locally convex space $X$ let us denote by $X^{\mathbb N}$ and $X_{\mathbb N}$ the direct product and the locally convex sum of contable copies of $X$. Then I would think that $({\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N})'_{\beta}\otimes_{\pi}{\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N}=({\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N})_{\mathbb N}\ne({\mathbb R}_{\mathbb N})^{\mathbb N}=L_{\beta}({\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N})$.

Comment: The first equality does not hold as projective tensor products do not commute with direct sums.

Comment: The author of the book you mention is Hans *Jarchow*.

Answer (score 8):

It is indeed true that for a nuclear Frechet space $F$, the *complete* projective tensor product $F'_\beta \tilde{\otimes}_\pi F$ is *isomorphic* to $L_\beta(F,F)$.
The mistake is your claim that the complete projective tensor product $E\tilde{\otimes}_\pi F$ consists of convergent series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n e_n \otimes f_n$. This is true if $E$ and $F$ are *both* Frechet spaces or *both* strong duals of Frechet spaces. In the *mixed* case as in your situation
the complete *inductive* tensor product can be described by such series but it is much smaller than the projective tensor product.

EDIT: I meant the *inductive* tensor product (the injective coincides indeed with the projective one because of nuclearity).

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is wrong (unfortunately, I can't comment, so here is another answer instead). 
Now, I'm quoting from "Notes on locally convex vector spaces" by J.L. Taylor.

Since $F$ is nuclear, the (completed, you are right, I meant that) injective and projective tensor products agree, so "is smaller than" doesn't apply here.

Furthermore, theorem 21.5.9 in Yarchow explicitely states that the maps are *homeomorphisms*, and not just an *isomorphism*.
We have:

$F'_\beta \hat{\otimes}_\pi F=F'_\beta \hat{\otimes}_\epsilon 
F=L_\beta(F,F)$

(corrolary 5.19 in the aforemention lecture notes). Thus the injective tensor product is just as big, "is smaller than" does not make much sense here.

Also, we have (proposition 3.5):

Any  bilinear continuous map $\phi : F'_\beta \times F \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ extends to a map $\phi' : F'_\beta \hat{\otimes}_\pi F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Which brings me to the real answer to the problem, which I just found myself:

Now, this would be fine if the trace was indeed continuous. But: Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, $V$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}_\mathbb{N}$. Then, we always have: $U(V)=\mathbb{R}$, as can always be seen by choosing a sufficiently small open subset. Hence, the trace is *not* a bilinear continous map, hence can not be extended! Please correct me if you see any mistake, but I think that is the answer, no?

Comment: J.L.R: you seem to have created two different accounts. One for the question, and one for the answer... (you can see that the icons next to "J.L.R" are different).

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. The registration process was a little confusing to me.

Comment: You could try requesting the moderators to merge the accounts --- please visit MO.meta e.g., http://meta.mathoverflow.net/search?q=merge to figure out how!

Comment: Nah, I got it working now, I am fine, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. For any non-normed locally convex space $F$ the *evalution* $F'_\beta \times F \to \mathbb C$, $(\phi,x)\mapsto \phi(x)$ is separately continuous but discontinuous. This shows that the *inductive* tensor product $F'_\beta \otimes_\iota F$ (defined by the universal property, that all separately continuous bilinear maps factorize continuously) has a much finer topology than the projective tensor product.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense, thank you very much! Would you happen to be able to recommend any literature on the construction of the inductive tensor product?

Comment: The inductive tensor product apparently did not find many applications. I only know Grothendieck's "these" as a reference.